# Automapper .net 8 conflict?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a nugget named Judy that uses .NET Core 3.1 and AutoMapper version 10.0.0. I updated my project to .NET 8 and AutoMapper 12, but it is generating the following error, and I don't know what to do to fix it.

Error: Method not found: 'AutoMapper.TypeMap AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(System.Type, System.Type)'.

Version automapper nugget judy

// AutoMapper, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005
// Assembly reference loading information:
// There were some problems during assembly reference load, see below for more information!
// Error: Could not find reference: AutoMapper, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005

I want to highlight that I don't have access to the source code of the nugget.

Comment: Judy doesn't appear to be in NuGet.org so I can't inspect it, but my guess is that AutoMapper v12 contains breaking changes compared to v10 (hence the major version increasing by two) and it is no longer compatible with Judy. You'll either need to downgrade AutoMapper to v10 (or maybe v11 will work) or get Judy to update their dependency to fix the compatibility.